# MySQL - how to refresh table after a large number of deletes

Tags: mysql

I just ran a simple delete query in the form:

```
DELETE*FROM [db.table] WHERE id < [value];
```

This deleted about 80 million rows from the database (I had archived the data and no longer needed it).  This system constantly has data coming in at a rate of about 20 inserts per second and now there are a couple thousand entries in the database again.

If I run a query (limited to 1000 rows) that sorts descending, like this:

```
SELECT*FROM [db.table] ORDER BY id DESC;
```

I immediately get the results back, however if I sort ascending, like this:

```
SELECT*FROM [db.table] ORDER BY id ASC;
```

the query will timeout after 10 minutes.  It seems to me (and this is just a guess) that the query is going through all of the ids for my recently deleted rows and never gets to the newest data. Is that possible?

How do I get 'sort ASC' query to work?  Do I need to do some sort of refresh? Thanks

Comment: Do you have an index on this field?

Comment: Yes, I believe it is an Index_type of BTREE. Does that sound right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider running MYSQL's `optimize table` after doing big deletes.

> Reorganizes the physical storage of table data and associated index data, to reduce storage space and improve I/O efficiency when accessing the table. The exact changes made to each table depend on the storage engine used by that table.

Docs here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html

Comment: I ran the optimize command in on a replica of the database in a sandbox.  This returned a message that said "Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead".  What is this telling me? Thanks.

Comment: It means your table is probably innodb instead of MyISAM, and that mySQL is instead trying to optimize your table a different way.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to set back the auto-increment value by using this smart way:

```
DELETE * FROM [db.table] WHERE id < [value],
ALTER TABLE [db.table] AUTO_INCREMENT = [value];
```

By the way, I always set up an **unsigned** integer of primary id col:

```
ALTER TABLE [db.table] CHANGE `id` `id` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```